# Complex Number problem (dup.)

Tags: complex-numbers

I can’t solve this problem.

> When $w=\cos 20^\circ +i\sin 20^\circ$, $\dfrac 1 {|w+2w^2+3w^3+\ldots+18w^{18}|} = {}$?

First, I solved the equation of the denominator using the De Moivre's formula. I don't know if it's right, but the value of real part came out simply. But the value of imaginary part is too complicated.

Secondly, I thought about Euler's formula, but I couldn't solve it. The answer seems to come in the form of sin10 or sin20.

Comment: Hello! May you please edit your question to show what steps you have taken to solve this problem, and to highlight which exact parts you do not understand?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Here is a hint: consider the sum of the (finite) geometric sequence, differentiate it and multiply it by $w$.

Comment: Thank you. I edited text

Comment: $w+2w^2+\cdots+18w^{18}=w(1+2w+\cdots+18w^{17})=w{d\over dw}(w+w^2+\cdots+w^{18})=w{d\over dw}{w(w^{18}-1)\over w-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify this denominator.
It is akin to a geometric series.

$(w+2w+\cdots +17w^{17}+18 w^{18})\\
\frac {(1-w)(w+2w^2 + \cdots+17w^{17}+18 w^{18})}{w-1}\\
\frac{w - w^2 + 2w^2 - 2w^3 + \cdots + 17w^{17} - 17w^{18} + 18 w^{18} - 18w^{19}}{1-w}\\
\frac {w + w^2 + \cdots + w^{18} - 18w^{19}}{1-w}$

Now we have an actual geometric series plus one more term.

$\frac {w + w^2 + \cdots + w^{18}}{1-w} - \frac {18w^{19}}{1-w}\\
\frac {(1-w)(w + w^2 + \cdots + w^{18})}{(1-w)^2} - \frac {18w^{19}}{1-w}\\
\frac {w-w^{19}}{(1-w)^2} - \frac {18w^{19}}{1-w}$

$w = e^{\frac {i\pi}{9}}\\
w^{19} = e^{\frac {i\pi}{9}+2\pi i} = w$

If this looks alien to you, you can find the same result using de Moivre's formula. $(\cos 20^\circ + i\sin 20^\circ)^{18} = 1$

So, our denominator simplifies to $-\frac {18w}{1-w}$

$\frac {|1-w|}{|18w|}$

$|w| = 1$
$|1-w|$ equals the length of the segment that is the base of an equilateral triangle with vertex angle $20^\circ$

$\frac {|1-w|}{18} = \frac {2\sin \frac {\pi}{18}}{18} = \frac {\sin 10^\circ}{9}$

Comment: Thank you. But in the first expression, isn't the denominator not w-1, but 1-w?